# home directory in google colab GUI sidebar

Tags: google-colaboratory

I can't seem to figure out where exactly is a home directory in Google Colab sidebar.

I have created a `Test` directory in `~/`. I can't sort of find where is it in GUI mode. Anything I download in jupyter notebook goes in the `content` directory but I believe that's not `~`. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks

[image: Google Colab]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The home directory is `/root`. A few ways to check:

[image]

Comment: so if I create a `test` directory. Where can I see? `/root`? It's empty

Comment: Browsing to `/root` after `!mkdir ~/Test` worked as expected for me. Perhaps you need to hit the 'refresh' button in the file browser?